# FluentValidation on collection of strings

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following code:

```
public partial class CustomerContactCommunicationValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerCommunication>
{
    public CustomerContactCommunicationValidator()
    {
       CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

        RuleFor(x => x.PhoneNumbers).SetCollectionValidator(new FaxPhoneNumberValidator("PhoneNumber"));
        RuleFor(x => x.FaxNumbers).SetCollectionValidator(new FaxPhoneNumberValidator("Faxnumbers"));
    }               
}

public class FaxPhoneNumberValidator : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public FaxPhoneNumberValidator(string collectionName)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).Length(0, 35).OverridePropertyName(collectionName);
    }
}
```

PhoneNumbers and FaxNumbers are declared as List.

My unit tests:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("ValidationTests")]
    public void ShouldHaveErrorWhenPhoneNumberIsLongerThan35Charachters()
    {
        validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.PhoneNumbers, new List<string>() { "123456789012345678901234567890123456111" });
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("ValidationTests")]
    public void ShouldNotHaveErrorWhenPhoneNumberIsSmallerThan35Charachters()
    {
        validator.ShouldNotHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.PhoneNumbers, new List<string>() { "0032486798563" });
    }
```

The first test fails, the second one does not.
Also when I do a live test, it succeeds on a phone number which is larger than 35 charachters.

I've seen other questions about this: [How do you validate against each string in a list using Fluent Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190316/how-do-you-validate-against-each-string-in-a-list-using-fluent-validation)

But I really don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, have you tried the code below? Does it work for you as well?

Answer (score 2):

Check this example it might clarify all your doubts.

**Validation classes:**

```
using FluentValidation;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test.Validator
{

    public class EmailCollection
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> email { get; set; }

    }

    public class EmailValidator:  AbstractValidator<string>
    {
        public EmailValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x).Length(0, 5);
        }

    }

    public class EmailListValidator: AbstractValidator<EmailCollection>
    {
        public EmailListValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.email).SetCollectionValidator(new EmailValidator());
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
public class CustomerContactCommunicationValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomerCommunication>
{
   public CustomerContactCommunicationValidator()
   {
       RuleForEach(x => x.PhoneNumbers).Length(0, 35);
       RuleForEach(x => x.FaxNumbers).Length(0, 35);
   }
}
```