# Fluent Validation on List of string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, fluentvalidation

I have a list of strings and I have to define a rule to validate my ModelState in Web API.

Each string element of this list should have length = 2 only. not greater than 2 or less than 2.

I wrote something like this, but it is not working.

```
RuleFor(m => m.State.TrueForAll(x => x.Length == 2)).Equals(true);
```

could someone help me out here.

Comment: Shouldn't that be more like `RuleFor(m => m.State).Must(s => s.TrueForAll(x => x.Length == 2))`;  `RuleFor` is meant to select the property you want to validate, then you do the validation after that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you validate against each string in a list using Fluent Validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190316/how-do-you-validate-against-each-string-in-a-list-using-fluent-validation)

Comment: @juharr This worked! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
bool isAllValid = yourList.All(x => x.Length == 2);
```

Where `yourList` be the input List, after execution the value of `isAllValid` will be true if all the elements of the list are of length `2`. if any of the item in the string is less than `2` or greater than `2` then the value of `isAllValid` will be false. If you enclose this under a method then its signature would be:

```
public bool IsAllItemsValid(List<string> yourList)
{
    return yourList.All(x => x.Length == 2);
}
```